# mysql slow log query details about Query_time

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I am using mysql :  5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log (Ubuntu) and I enabled slow log query ,slow log query time set is 2 sec 
for details :

```
show variables like 'slow_launch_time';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| slow_launch_time | 2     |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and in my.cnf :

```
long_query_time = 2
```

it means any query takes more than 2 sec, it will stored in  mysql slow log query.

when I tried this using select sleep(1) ; select sleep(2) ;  select sleep(3) ;
and viewed slow log query ,only sleep(2) and sleep(3) saved in slow log query with 
Query_time: # Query_time: 2.000263  and # Query_time: 3.000278  respectively .
but I saw many queries which have Query_time less than 2 sec also saved in slow log query

for more details :

```
# Query_time: 0.001775  Lock_time: 0.000154 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 120
```

why this type of query saved in my slow log , I don't understand ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because [`log_queries_not_using_indexes`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-queries-not-using-indexes) is on:

> If you are using this option with the slow query log enabled, queries that are expected to retrieve all rows are logged. See [Section 5.2.5, “The Slow Query Log”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html). This option does not necessarily mean that no index is used. For example, a query that uses a full index scan uses an index but would be logged because the index would not limit the number of rows.